# How to retrieve recently uploaded file name in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am developing an website in php where user can upload csv file. after clicking 'upload' button, file is renamed and saved in the format 'upload'.time(). I need to show the contents of the uploaded file just after uploading the file. 
So far I have been able to upload file correctly and I have tested with a static filename and have been able to read csv file perfectly. but when I am trying to get recently uploaded file name just after uploading I am not getting anywhere. searched through the whole site but didn't get any solution that worked for me.
I am using codeigniter 2.1.0 .

Controller file:

```
<?php     
class Csv_ci extends CI_Controller {

function is_logged() {
    $is_logged_in = $this->session->userdata('is_logged_in');
    if (!isset($is_logged_in) || $is_logged_in != true)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

function index() {
    if ($this->is_logged() == TRUE) {
        $this->load->model('Csv_model');

        if ($this->input->post('upload')) {
            $name = $this->Csv_model->do_upload();
            //print_r($name);
            if (isset($name)) {
                $filePath = "localhost/map_ci/csv/" . $name;
                //$filePath = './csv/bank_data.csv';
                $row = 1;
                if (($handle = fopen($filePath, "r")) !== FALSE) {
                    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) {
                        $num = count($data);

                        $file_data[$row]['district_name'] = $data[1];
                        $file_data[$row]['bank_name'] = $data[2];
                        $file_data[$row]['area_name'] = $data[3];
                        $file_data[$row]['address'] = $data[4];
                        $row++;
                    }

                    fclose($handle);
                }
                $this->load->view('csvshow', array('file_data' => $file_data));
            }
        }
    }
    else $this->load->view('invalid_member');
     }
}
```

Model file:

```
 <?php

class Csv_model extends CI_Model {

var $gallery_path;
var $gallery_path_url;

function Csv_model() {
    parent::__construct();


    $this->gallery_path = realpath(APPPATH . '../csv');
    $this->gallery_path_url = base_url() . 'csv/';
}

function do_upload() {
    $config = array(
        'upload_path' => $this->gallery_path,
        'allowed_types' => 'text/csv|csv|text/x-comma-separated-values|text/comma-separated-values|application/x-csv|text/x-csv|text/csv|application/csv|',
        'max_size' => '5000',
        'file_name' => 'upload' . time()
    );


    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if (!$this->upload->do_upload())
        echo $this->upload->display_errors();
    else {
        $file_info = $this->upload->data();
        $csvfilepath = "csv/" . $file_info['file_name'];
        $this->addfromcsv($csvfilepath);
        $filename = $file_info['file_name'];
        // print_r($filename);
        return $filename;
    }
} 
}
```

to retrieve file name I am doing  `file_info['file_name']`.
Please help me find a solution.

Update:
My current problem has been solved after removing `$csvfilepath = "csv/" . $file_info['file_name'];
            $this->addfromcsv($csvfilepath);` these two lines from my code.Now its returning uploaded file name.yet to check whether fully working or not.

Update 2: code functioning well
thanks all for your help.

Comment: are you sure $name contains something? If I'm not mistaken you need to make use of the address of the file in the file system instead of localhost/map_ci/csv/ it should be something like d:/folder/filename.jpg

Comment: I tried printing whatever in $filename but nothing was dumped so $name is not returning anything. first I need the name and then I can correct the filepath properly. any idea on how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return the concatenation of `$config['upload_path']` & `$config['file_name']` from `do_upload()` and use it to read the corresponding file.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in `$this->upload->data()`

try returning `$config['file_name']` from `do_upload()`

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = $this->upload->data();
print_r($data);
```

returns:

```
Array
(
[file_name]    => mypic.jpg
[file_type]    => image/jpeg
[file_path]    => /path/to/your/upload/
[full_path]    => /path/to/your/upload/jpg.jpg
[raw_name]     => mypic
[orig_name]    => mypic.jpg
[client_name]  => mypic.jpg
[file_ext]     => .jpg
[file_size]    => 22.2
[is_image]     => 1
[image_width]  => 800
[image_height] => 600
[image_type]   => jpeg
[image_size_str] => width="800" height="200"
)`
```

so: `$file_name = $data['file_name'];`

-or-

`$file = $data['file_path'].$data['file_name'];`

Comment: thanks. even though I tried doing same as your suggestion first `$file_info['file_name']` ,it didn't work , but now its working when I removed `$csvfilepath = "csv/" . $file_info['file_name'];
            $this->addfromcsv($csvfilepath);`

Answer (score 0):

just use:

```
$this->upload->file_name;
```